# "-ic" vs "-ical", which to use

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

Is there a rule about when an adjective should end with "ic" or "ical"?

Geometr-**ic**
Analyt-**ical**
Theoret-**ical**
Kinet-**ic**

Comment: meta, "The Cambridge Guide to English Usage" has an entry named "-ic/-ical" in which it is said "Is there any reason for preferring one over the other? Often the answer is no." What does "Often" mean there? "Often" means that you should consult a dictionary each time you have to use an ic/ical adjective!

Comment: ... in fact in certain cases there is a great divergence in meaning, like it happen to econimic/al, historic/al and politic/al, but, fortunately, apart kinetic/al, the other adjectives you cited don't have this problem.

Comment: There's some very useful information in [this answer to a similar question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/6600/2637), but the bottom line, as @Carlo says, is that you probably ought to consult a dictionary fairly often (but if you don't have any reference tools to hand and you have to make a choice on the fly, you'll get it right more often than not if you always go for **-ic**).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NOAD says that the *-ical* suffix is used to form adjectives:

- Corresponding to nouns or adjectives usually ending in *-ic* (such as *comical* corresponding to *comic*)
- Corresponding to nouns ending in *-y* (such as *pathological* corresponding to *pathology*)

As for the words you list, the NOAD says:

- *Geometric* and *geometrical* are both adjectives, with the latter being a derivative of the first
- *Analytic* is another term for *analytical*
- *Theoretic* is another term for *theoretical*
- Kinetical is not a word listed by the NOAD

In some cases, a suffix is preferred over the other one, but there isn't a rule that explains in every case when to use one or the other.