# Difference between anthropometric and anthropometrical

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, adjectives, word-difference

I came across the words *anthropometric* and *anthropometrical* in the context of clinical studies.
According to en.wiktionary.org, both are adjectives and they are explained as follows:

> [anthropometric](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anthropometric) = "of, or relating to anthropometry"
>
> [anthropometrical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anthropometrical) = "Pertaining to anthropometry"

To me this sounds pretty similar.

**What exactly is the difference between them?** 
Could I replace one by the other in all cases? 
Is there a subtle difference in their meaning that I did not get? 
Or is there maybe a difference in usage (e.g. one is more colloquial; one is more frequent in the UK; one is only used in certain context, etc.)?

Comment: The full OED specifically says that ***anthropometrical** = Of or relating to the rate of increase in a human population* is an ***obsolete nonce-use***. Other than that, both terms are equivalent (meaning *Of or relating to the measurement of the human body; relating to anthropometry*), but the shorter/simpler form is [vastly more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anthropometrical%2Canthropometric&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canthropometrical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canthropometric%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Related: *[“-ic” vs “-ical”, which to use?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8137)* and at EL&U, *[Why is it “geometric” but “theoretical”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6581)*

Comment: I must admit I had to look this one up, since I'd never come across *either* version before (or if I *have*, I probably just dismissed it as a misused alternative to ***anthropomorphic*** or ***anthropocentric***). It would be stretching a point to suppose that *either* of OP's versions could be called "colloquial".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Glad we both learned something :) - Do you mind turning your comment to an answer?

Comment: +1 @choster I was not aware that this relates to a more general question, thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [full OED specifically says](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8442#eid2099900) that ***anthropometrical*** = Of or relating to the rate of increase in a human population is an obsolete nonce-use. Other than that, both terms are equivalent (meaning [*Of or relating to the measurement of the human body; relating to anthropometry*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8441?redirectedFrom=anthropometric#eid)), but the shorter/simpler form is vastly more common.

[Here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anthropometric%2Canthropometrical%2Canthropomorphic%2Canthropocentric%2Canthropomorphical%2Canthropocentrical&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canthropometric%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canthropometrical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canthropomorphic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canthropocentric%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canthropomorphical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canthropocentrical%3B%2Cc0) showing relative prevalence of OP's words and closely related terms, from which you can see that nobody has much use for the ***-ical*** versions (especially, *today*)...

[image]