# Semantic (or Semantical) Difference Between Adjectives Ending With "-ic" and "-ical"

Tags: difference, adjectives, suffixes

I have seen some adjectives, having the same roots, ending "**-ic**" and "**-ical**" without understanding any semantic(al) difference between them, for example,

- *semantic* vs. *semantical*
- *conic* vs. *conical*
- *logistic* vs. *logistical*
- *bibliographic* vs. *bibliographical*
- ...

As far as I know, the suffix "**-ic**" means having the nature of while the suffix "**-al**" means relating to. So I think when an adjective is formed by adding the suffix "**-ic**" to a noun, it does not necessary and meaningful to add the suffix "**-al**" to the formed adjective to create another adjective with the same meaning. I wonder whether there is any semantic(al) difference between such pairs of adjectives.

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to say authoritatively that there's no difference between any two such pairs of adjectives --so I won't give this as an answer-- but I can say I haven't found such a pair where one word has a clearly different meaning to the other. One is usually more commonly used than the other (= *semantic, conical, logistical, bibliographic, grammatical, ironic*...), but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["-ic" vs "-ical", which to use](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8137/ic-vs-ical-which-to-use)